# MD5sum differs from what was uploaded

Tags: php, request-headers

I check the MD5sum of an .iso file before uploading to my website using Filezilla in active mode. The MD5sum is calculated on the website and matches what was calculated before upload. If I download the same file from the website using the following code, the MD5sum is different.

```
    <?php

$php_scripts = '../../php/';
require $php_scripts . 'PDO_Connection_Select.php';
require $php_scripts . 'GetUserIpAddr.php';
function mydloader($l_filename=NULL)
{
$ip = GetUserIpAddr();
if (!$pdo = PDOConnect("foxclone"))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to database" ;
    exit;
}
    if( isset( $l_filename ) ) {
 //       var_dump($ip,$l_filename);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO download (IP_ADDRESS, FILENAME) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->execute([$ip, $l_filename]) ;

        header('Content-Type: octet-stream');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$l_filename}");
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');

        readfile($l_filename); 

        echo "Made it here";
        }
    else {
        echo "isset failed";
        }
}

mydloader($_GET["f"]);
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT: I found the difference by opening both the original iso and the downloaded iso in atom editor. The downloaded version has the following added to the start of the file:

```
herestring(14) “xx.xxx.xxx.xxx” <— my ip
string(17) “foxclone35-02.iso”
herestring(14) “xx.xxx.xxx.xxx”
string(17) “foxclone35-02.iso”
```

Comment: Because you sent additional output to the client, after the file contents … what did you _think_ `echo "Made it here";` does, hm?

Comment: Removed the echo statement, still get differing MD5sums

Comment: Then open the file with a text- or hex-editor, and check if the start and end match the content of the original file, or if anything else made its way into the output there.

Comment: @CBroe - see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing some debugging code that was being added to the downloaded file.